# How to reset neovim setting on MacOS to its default completely?

Tags: neovim, macos

I installed neovim on MacOS Big Sur via homebrew. Then created the `init.vim` using [vim-bootstrap](https://vim-bootstrap.com/) (the languages I picked were C, Go, Haskell, Ocaml, and Rust) and put it on `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`.

Then I opened a C code file and neovim automatically pulled some C-related plugins. Overall seemed OK.

When opening another code files, nvim complained about "command not found" on `init.vim`. After some inspection, I guess because Haskell and Ocaml compilers hadn't been installed. So I wiped the entire nvim config directory, and created a new `init.vim` (without Haskell and Ocaml).

I ran nvim, then saw this errors. How to fix these?

[image]

Comment: Just remove everything inside init.vim.

Comment: you have references to the `vim-plug` plugin inside your vimrc, but you haven't installed it. So either remove those `Plug` sections, or install [vim-plug pluginmanager](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your terminal - you can copy the text and [edit] your question to paste the text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you accidental removed the location of there vim should store plugins in your init.vim

Try replacing your line

`call plug#begin`

with

`call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')`

Comment: Welcome to vi.se! The messages `Not an editor command` related to `plug#begin` and `Plug` show that OP hasn't installed the plugin manager vim-plug (they need to download the file and install it as described in vim-plug's README) here your solution will still generate the same errors because without reinstalling vim-plug they will keep trying to call `plug#begin` which doesn't exists.